# How to publish an UWP application

Tags: uwp, windows-store

I have an Azure subscription and have access to the Microsoft Partner Center with my Azure AD account. I am global administrator, so I should have all the rights. This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-your-app-by-reserving-a-name) tells me that I should reserve a name in the MS Partner Center, but I don't have this option. I do have a very complex Partner Center and I have checked everything, but I can't find the option to publish my UWP application. I need to publish my app soon, but I don't know where to look anymore. Unfortunately, there is no support option where I can create a ticket for MS support.

Answer (score 0):

To publish your app into the store, you need to register a developer account that could publish the app instead of using the Azure account.

Please check this document [Opening a developer account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/opening-a-developer-account) to register your developer account.

Answer (score 0):

I have had contact with Microsoft today and you cannot use an Azure AD account for this purpose. You need to create a Microsoft account, register as a developer and then associate the Azure AD tenant.